# Will application_start event be fired when use auto-start mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0

I have read this article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx about auto-start mode in asp.net4.0 and still don't understand is application_start event fired on application warm-up or not? Article said that application are automaticaly preloaded with the logic, described in class, registered as serviceAutoStartProvider. But what about application start, is "preloaded" means that application_start also fires, or it fires only after preloading on first request?

Comment: How about simply trying it by yourself? Subscribe to the event and e.g. write some trace/log entry to find out.

Comment: i have no IIS installed and using visual studio included server for development. I think someone can know it, can save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event **Application_Start** is **not** fired by the IIS AutoStart feature. It is still fired upon first request.

You may check that the application is ready in "Application_Start" and run the init code if you find it is not. This way the application is compatible with IIS Express (it does not support AutoStart) and IIS 7.5.